# How to change the color of a visited link in top menu

Tags: css

I have this in CSS

```
header.site-header .col-sm-6 .menu-global-container {
    a:visited {color: #888888;}
}
```

But I'm sure something is very wrong here as it is not working at all

Its a top menu on my site which has a link to a menu item which opens a page on my site.

This is the only way I could add a page link to this specific top menu in the theme I am using

Comment: Post your html or make a codepen/snippet but just a guess try `header a:visited{color:#f93}`

Answer (score 1):

```
header.site-header .col-sm-6 .menu-global-container {
    a:visited {color: #888888;}
}
```

Is an invalid CSS selector. If you want to use only CSS, use like:

```
header.site-header .col-sm-6 .menu-global-container a:visited{
    color: #888888;
}
```

---

But you can use some CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) if you want to nest elements.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing your css around like this to see if it works

```
header.site-header a:visited{color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `header a:visited{color:#f93}`

As it stands now your css is invalid you are unable to nest tags like you are doing now unless you are using scss or some sort of css pre-processor